# Return bus ticket from Bangalore to Goa?

Tags: public-transport, india, buses, goa-india, bangalore

Can we get bus tickets for going from Bangalore to Goa and back (tickets for comfortable air-conditioned buses) at the last minute (few minutes before the departure of bus) easily, without any difficulty?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The state run transport company, [KSRTC](http://www.ksrtc.in) has very good well maintained a/c buses to Goa from Bangalore. You can check the availability and book tickets online from their website. Make sure to select service class as 'Premium' to get a/c buses in your search results.

Since Goa being a well known tourist place and April-June is summer vacation, it is advisable to book tickets in advance. Or plan your journey on week days.

Answer (score 6):

You can, but it's not recommended. As mentioned by the previous answer, Goa being a popular destination, the buses are usually booked out. It is preferable to book your tickets at least a day or two in advance.

[Redbus](http://www.redbus.in) is a portal where you can check out the availability of private buses.